# How to select data from imported excel file between two date ranges in R

Tags: r

Below is the format of my imported excel file for one whole month

```
    Exch_Cash Token_Cash   LTT_Cash                 LTP_Cash  LTT_FO                   Price_FO

1   NC        2885         2014-01-27 09:07:24.000  856.00    2014-01-24 15:29:59.000  867.55
2   NC        2885         2014-01-28 09:15:01.000  857.05    2014-01-27 09:15:01.000  858.60
3   NC        2885         2014-01-28 09:15:02.000  857.90    2014-01-27 09:15:02.000  858.80
4   NC        2885         2014-01-29 09:15:03.000  857.90    2014-01-27 09:15:03.000  859.05
5   NC        2885         2014-01-30 09:15:04.000  857.40    2014-01-27 09:15:04.000  858.00
6   NC        2885         2014-01-31 09:15:05.000  857.55    2014-01-27 09:15:05.000  858.45
```

I have to select a weekly data based on the date range in field `LTT_Cash` (contains both date and time) and have to put it in a separate data frame. I tried many methods but I am not able to convert `LTT_Cash` in date format understood by R. I am also not sure which function should be used to select data between two date ranges.

Answer (score 0):

what about

```
as.POSIXlt("2014-01-27 09:07:24.000")
```

You can also calculate with this format:

```
> as.POSIXlt("2014-01-27 09:07:24.000") - as.POSIXlt("2014-01-24 15:29:59.000")
> Time difference of 2.734317 days
```